# FontAwsome Icon in PHP with if-statement

Tags: php, mysql, font-awesome

I want to show a Font Awesome Icon in a PHP table.
It should show the fa-eye icon if there is a 'ja' in the row named 'visible', else it should show the fa-eye-slash icon.

here is my code:

```
<?php 
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM gamesnw ORDER BY datum");
$result = $statement->execute();
$count = 1;
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['tag']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['datum']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['zeit']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['ort']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['liga']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['heim']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['gast']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['sr1']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['sr2']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['reserve']."</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    print '<a href="gamesettings.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-default btn1">Ändern</a>';
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo if .$row['visible'] == 'ja'.'<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>' else '<i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>';
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

I tried it in the third last line, but it dosen't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend you stop echoing HTML and instead switch from PHP to HTML when outputting data. It's much simpler to get the syntax right and your IDE will pick up on the syntax as well. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b711447b8779bc2b8ae5b4069b1ade1756e0c35

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 echo '<i class="fa '.($row['visible'] === 'ja' ? 'fa-eye' : 'fa-eye-slash').'"></i>';
```

Comment: its too lengthy

Comment: And now? ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
echo if .$row['visible'] == 'ja'.'<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>' else '<i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>';
       ^^ Error
```

to this

```
echo ($row['visible'] == 'ja') ? '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>';
```

[Get more about **Single line `IF`**](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)